Using psycopg2 placeholders
I have the following code:
query = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE service IN %s AND location LIKE '%London%'"
values = (services,) # services is a tuple of strings.

cur.execute(query, values)

When I execute this code I get the following error:
--> cur.execute(query, values)
IndexError: tuple index out of range

After researching the topic a little bit, I think that the %L in the query is being detected as a placeholder, so the psycopg2 library is trying to insert data there, but there is no more data in the values tuple.
I have tried escaping the % sign using the following query:
query = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE service IN %s AND location LIKE '%%London%'"

but this has also not worked.
How can I fix this issue and get the expected behaviour?

Doubling the % wildcards works for me - but note you need to double both - '%%London%%' - in the question you have not doubled the second '%%London%'.

The docs Passing parameters are a wonderful resource: When parameters are used, in order to include a literal % in the query you can use the %% string:.

Instead of LIKE you can also use the regex expression ~ so you don't need the % and % anymore: AND location ~ 'London'. It also gives you extra regex functionality.

from the docs, a better and easier approach for such use cases would be to use POSIX regex over LIKE or SIMILAR TO operators,
query = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE service IN %s AND location ~ '.*London.*'"

im not sure about its compatibility with different psycopg as well as posgresql versions.

You can safely format your query using the pscyopg2.sql library.
The below code adds a placeholder value for each element within the services tuple into the query string, then you can execute as you normally would.
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE service IN ({}) AND location LIKE '%%London%%'")
formatted_query = query.format(sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(services)))

cur.execute(formatted_query, services)


Your original query did the same thing and properly escaped also, in a more compact form. Your only mistake was not using %% to escape the %.
